# size of memory of computer that uses 16 bits memory address

Tags: binary, hex, decimal, complement

If the memory address of a computer uses 16 bits, what is the size of its memory? I find many references online but I can't be certain which are relevant. Thank you.
2^16?

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address#Word_size_versus_address_size):

> For instance, a computer said to be "32-bit" also usually allows
>   32-bit memory addresses; a byte-addressable 32-bit computer can
>   address 2^32 = 4,294,967,296 bytes of memory, or 4 gibibytes (GiB).
>   This seems logical and useful, as it allows one memory address to be
>   efficiently stored in one word.

So to answer your question, in general, yes a 16-bit computer can address 2^16 bytes of memory per word write.